# How to handle two different views height and scroll in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist, which contains a horizontal Scrollview (for tab navigation) and navigation menu.

currently, when I scrolled 1st view and then swipe to 2nd view it automatically scrolled. and the 2nd view height is also the same as the 1st view.

how can I separate both views by height and scroll?

here is my code.

```
import {
    View,
    Text,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
  } from "react-native";
  import React, { useRef } from "react";
  import Animated, {
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useSharedValue,
  } from "react-native-reanimated";
  
  const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  
  export default function () {
    const scrollRef = useRef();
    const scrollX = useSharedValue(0);
  
    const scrollXAnimateStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      return {
        transform: [
          {
            translateX: scrollX.value,
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  
    const View1 = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "lime",
            width: deviceWidth,
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 35,
            }}
          >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, quos
            incidunt consequatur voluptas labore recusandae sapiente dolorum
            voluptatibus eaque harum esse. Maxime veniam cum suscipit ipsum
            laudantium officiis dolore! Dicta.
            {"\n\n\n"}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, quos
            incidunt consequatur voluptas labore recusandae sapiente dolorum
            voluptatibus eaque harum esse. Maxime veniam cum suscipit ipsum
            laudantium officiis dolore! Dicta.
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    };
    const View2 = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "cyan",
            width: deviceWidth,
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
            }}
          >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, quos
            incidunt consequatur voluptas labore recusandae sapiente dolorum
            voluptatibus eaque harum esse. Maxime veniam cum suscipit ipsum
            laudantium officiis dolore! Dicta.
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    };
  
    const HeaderCom = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 50,
              backgroundColor: "yellow",
              flexDirection: "row",
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                width: deviceWidth / 2,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });
              }}
            >
              <Text>View 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                width: deviceWidth / 2,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: deviceWidth, animated: true });
              }}
            >
              <Text>View 2</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              {
                height: 3,
                backgroundColor: "black",
                width: deviceWidth / 2,
              },
              scrollXAnimateStyle,
            ]}
          ></Animated.View>
        </View>
      );
    };
  
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <StatusBar barStyle={"dark-content"} />
        <FlatList
          data={[0, 1]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            if (item === 0) {
              return <HeaderCom />;
            } else {
              return (
                <ScrollView
                  ref={scrollRef}
                  bounces={false}
                  horizontal
                  pagingEnabled
                  scrollEventThrottle={16}
                  onScroll={(event) => {
                    scrollX.value = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / 2;
                  }}
                >
                  <View1 />
                  <View2 />
                </ScrollView>
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you simplify your code with the minimal usfull part please?

Comment: @devpolo Animation is the only extra code I guess.

Comment: provide actual output vs expected output